# glitches an black pixel appear with

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, particles

I use a particle system and an explode modifier to disintegrate two objects. For some reason, glitches and black pixels randomly appear in individual PNGs in the render sequence. In the rendered preview, the glitches are not visible. The glitches are definitely no "objects". They really are errors in the render. I am using ...

cycles
gpu compute
denoiser: optix
128 samples
motion blur: 0.6

... everything else is set to default.

Thank you for your help!
[image: Glitches]

[image: Preview]

Comment: i think with seeing just a few settings it will be pretty hard to find the cause of this. Providing your blend file would help a lot...

Comment: it's super strange, the problem only appears when I import the scene in the video editor and render it out there. but it does not appear when I render in the scene itself. So I kind of got rid of the problem without technically solving it. I'm gonna simplify the file and upload it when the render is done... hopefully the problem then be replicable.

Comment: Should be closed probably as a bug https://developer.blender.org/T82036